# Ionic 5 - SwipeToClose is impossible

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

My problem is quite simple : I try to implement a component in modal, but when I try to add SwipeToClose, it's not working (The modal stay static even if I try to swipe down) ...

I'm really confused, but I've create a Stackblitz to show you my issue in detail, maybe I miss something important ... : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-u4wmun

My component :

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  myModal:any;

  constructor(
    public modalController: ModalController
  ) {
  }

  async presentModal() {
    this.myModal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalComponent,
      swipeToClose: true,
      backdropDismiss: true
    });
    return await this.myModal.present();
  }

}
```

Thanks to your time !

PS : I try to use it in iOS only, I've already try on my iOS device and it's doesn't work too ...

Answer (score 3):

swipe to close is only available for modals in ios mode(currently ionic v5). So, specify the mode of your modal to be ios

```
   this.myModal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: ModalComponent,
  swipeToClose: true,
  mode: 'ios',
  backdropDismiss: true
});
```

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry ! I didn't know that I have to hold and swipe down ion-header ahahah

Answer (score 1):

SwipeToClose Gesture only works on IOS mode and could be applied on card modals and will be deprecated by next release. If you apply following method to IonContent element or first element in body, it detects swipeDown gesture and kinda solves that issue and works with all modes.

```
constructor(public gestureCtrl: GestureController) { }

swipeDownToCloseModal = (elm: HTMLElement)=>{
  const swipeGesture: Gesture = this.gestureCtrl.create({
    el:elm,
    threshold:1,
    maxAngle:95,
    gestureName:'swipeGesture',
    onEnd:e=>{
      if(e.velocityY>0.15 && e.deltaY>100 && elm.getBoundingClientRect().y===0){
        this.modal.dismiss(); //change
      }
    }
  });
  swipeGesture.enable(true);
};
```